# How can I extend the content negotiation behavior in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm working through a RESTful API design, and one of the questions I have about content negotiation I've posted to the Programmers StackExchange site [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/139654/rest-tradeoffs-between-content-negotiation-via-accept-header-versus-extensions).

Based on that, I'm interested in how I would support the following behavior in MVC4:

1. If an extension is specified on the URL (e.g., `GET /api/search.json` or `/api/search.xml`), override the default content negotiation behavior in MVC4
2. If no extension is specified, use the default behavior of examining the accept header value for `application/xml` or `application.json`.

What would be the cleanest / most straightforward way of capturing this extension and modifying the content negotiation behavior?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the UriPathExtensionMapping in the formatters to accomplish that. Those mappings let you "assign" an extension to a formatter, so that they're given precedence during content negotiation. You also need to add a route so that requests with "extension" are also accepted. The code below shows the changes required in the default template to enable this scenario.

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Api with extension",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}.{ext}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, ext = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.AddUriPathExtensionMapping("xml", "text/xml");
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.AddUriPathExtensionMapping("json", "application/json");
        BundleTable.Bundles.RegisterTemplateBundles();
    }
```

Comment: Awesome!  These formatting extensions also allow you to drive it via a query string parameter too, which I think I like better.

Comment: @BrandonLinton - how is the querystring parameter working for you?  did you have to do anything extra for it to intercept and convert?

Comment: @drzaus Instead of `AddUriPathExtensionMapping`, use the `AddQueryStringMapping` extension operation, like this: `formatter.AddQueryStringMapping("returnType", "json", "application/json");`

Comment: Is it possible to put the extension at the end, so instead of `/api/products.xml/6` you could use `/api/products/6.xml`?  This would allow browsers like IE to display the data instead of prompting for download.  I've tried `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}.{ext}"`, but that's causing an error in the parsing of id as an integer.

Comment: I got it working, it was a matter of the order in which the routes were added, where the routes with the {ext} should appear before those without.

Comment: I new to MVC, but I can't seem to get this working.  Anyone try this with VS 2012, and 4.5?  Everytime I use the .xml extension, I always get the 404 error.